# get the range values with bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I would like to get values of the range with bootstrap slider.

I have :

```
 <label "slider"><b>Lengths</b></label>
       <input id="slider1" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0.2" data-slider-max="9.8" data-slider-step="0.2" data-slider-value="[3.4,6.6]"/>
```

and my javascript code :

```
  var slider= new Slider("#slider1");
   slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
      console.log(slideEvt.value);
      });
```

but I get the following error (for console.log) : *undefined*

Finally, how to get the range values (min and max selected with mouse) ? Unfortunately, I can have only one value with the code above.

If anyone could help me, this would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: Did u try: $("#slider1").slider('getValue')

Comment: Or in your case: $(slideEvt.target').value

Comment: Was it helful? Can u give us some feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`.getValue()`](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#functions)** method to get the value of slider

```
var slider = new Slider("#slider1");
slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
 console.log(slider.getValue() );
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/detapa/2/edit?html,js,output**

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. You only missed an array index at

```
console.log(slideEvt.value);
```

So your code should be:

```
console.log(slideEvt.value[0]);
```

because bootstrap **range** slider returned an array.

Comment: `console.log(slideEvt.value[1]);` if you like to move to the next range